Yasnippet returns Wrong type argument: listp
After inserting the snippet I'm able to type the function name.
But after tabbing to args, I get the error Wrong type argument: listp on typing
Is it python-args-to-docstring failing at it's job?
I've enabled M-x debug on error though no error is raised.
The untouched snippet:
# -*- mode: snippet -*-
# name: function_docstring
# key: fd
# group: definitions
# NOTE: Use minimum indentation, because Emacs 25+ doesn't dedent docstrings.
# --
def ${1:name}($2):
\"\"\"$3
${2:$(python-args-to-docstring)}
\"\"\"
$0

Maybe offtopic though loading my init contains
Ignoring unknown directive "NOTE" in file: /home/user/.emacs.default/elpa/29.3/develop/yasnippet-snippets-20240603.757/snippets/python-mode/function_docstring


Do you see the same thing if you start with emacs -Q (no init file)? If not, bisect your init file to find the culprit.

I can reproduce this (but I haven't tried yet -Q as @Drew recommends) and it seems to me that indeed python-args-to-docstring is buggy: I was able to get slightly better results (no error, but still incorrect) by modifying the line that sets args in the let* from this: (args (python-split-args yas-text)) to this: (args (list (python-split-args yas-text))), but I don't know how yasnippet works (it seems to call this function on every character typed ?!?), so I would recommend you open an issue on the Github site.

For me it breaks/shutdown the lsp/pyright with the message Error in post-command-hook (lsp-signature): (error "The connected server(s) does not support method textDocument/signatureHelp.

I too have been having this problem. I actually fixed the function in .yas-setup.el in the python yasnippets directory. Here's the link to the code from my config: .yas-setup.el
I see a pull request on the snippets repo that has a sort-of fix. My code however tries to deal with complex type-hinting and strings with commas.
Let me know if this helps you.

I checked your solution - this does not work for me. I tried to compile your file and got three errors. This bug appeared (at least for me) with the yasnippet-snippets version 20240723; the previous one worked ok.
